# How to retrieve images from json array using alamofire?

Tags: swift

I have been trying to fetch details and images of a product from a server URL.I was able to get the details but not the image because image is a JSONarray.Please help me retrieve the images looking into the code. By the way, i have made use of "Alamofire" library. Thanks much!

JSON below:

```
 {
   "products": [
     {
        "product_id": 2,
        "name": "Ring",
        "description": "<p>    </p>",
        "price": 674,
        "master_variant_id": 2,
        "cost_currency": "USD",
        "shipping_and_returns": "",
        "city_or_state": null,
        "state_or_province": null,
        "user": {
            "company_name": "Gift Shop",
            "firstname": "giftvendor"
        },
        "master_variant_images": [
            "https://s3.amazonaws.com/webdevapp/app/public/spree/products/2/product/ri1.jpg?1476104874"
        ],
        "variants": [],
        "product_url": "http://staging.giftintime.com/mobile/products/2"
    }
}
```

**below is my code**

```
var gifther = [Gifther]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self

    Alamofire.request("http://staging.giftintime.com/mobile/categories/2/subcategories").responseJSON { (response) in

        let result = response.result

        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary <String, Any> {

            if let giftherdata = dict["products"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {

                for obj in giftherdata {

                    let giftintime = Gifther(giftherData: obj)
                    self.gifther.append(giftintime)
                    //print(giftintime)
                }
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! giftherTableViewCell

    let Gift: Gifther
    Gift = gifther[indexPath.row]

    //Displaying values
    cell.productnameLbl.text = Gift.productname
    cell.companynameLbl.text = "By  " + Gift.companyname
    cell.priceLbl.text = Gift.price
    cell.currencytypeLbl.text = Gift.currencytype

    //cell.imageview?.image = UIImage(named: Gift.imagesUrl)

   // cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

    //Displaying image



    Alamofire.request(Gift.imagesUrl  ).responseImage { (response) in
        debugPrint(response)

        if let image = response.result.value {

            cell.imageview.image = image

        }

    }

    /*

    Alamofire.request(Gift.imagesUrl as! URLRequestConvertible).responseData { (response) in
        if response.error == nil {
            print(response.result)
        }

        if let data = response.data {
            cell.imageview.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    */
    return cell
}
```

**below is my code from another class**

```
class Gifther {

var _productname:String?
var _price:String?
var _currencytype:String?
var _companyname:String?
var _imagesUrl:String?
var _productUrl:String?

//product details
var _descriptionData: String?
var _shippingAndreturns :String?

var productname:String {

    if _productname == nil {
        _productname = ""

    }
            return _productname!
}

var price:String {

    if _price == nil {
        _price = " "

    }
    return _price!
}

var currencytype:String {

    if _currencytype == nil {
        _currencytype = ""
    }
    return _currencytype!
}

var companyname:String {

    if _companyname == nil {
        _companyname = ""
    }
    return _companyname!
}

var imagesUrl:String {

    if _imagesUrl == nil {
        _imagesUrl = ""
    }
    return _imagesUrl!
}
```

//Product deails

```
var productUrl:String {

    if _productUrl == nil {
        _productUrl = ""
    }
    return _productUrl!
}

    var descriptionData:String {

        if _descriptionData == nil {
            _descriptionData = ""
        }
        return _descriptionData!
    }

var shippingAndreturns:String {

    if _shippingAndreturns == nil {
        _shippingAndreturns = ""
    }
    return _shippingAndreturns!
}



init(giftherData: Dictionary<String , Any>) {

    if let name = giftherData["name"] as? String {

        self._productname = name
    }

    if let Price = giftherData["price"] as? Float {
        self._price = String(describing: Price)
    }

    if let moneyType = giftherData["cost_currency"] as? String {

        self._currencytype = moneyType
    }

    if let companyname = giftherData["user"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {

        if let name = companyname["company_name"] as? String {

            self._companyname = name
        }
    }


    if let image = giftherData["master_variant_images"] as? NSArray {

       print("images are : \(image.count)")

        self._imagesUrl =  String(describing: image)

    }

   //Product details

    if let Producturl = giftherData["product_url"] as? String {

        self._productUrl = Producturl

    }

    if let description = giftherData["description"] as? String {

        self._productUrl = description
    }

    if let shippingAndreturns = giftherData["shipping_and_returns"] as? String {

        self._shippingAndreturns = shippingAndreturns
    }
     }

}
```

Comment: You declared variable  as var _imagesUrl:String?
But u assign as Array  if let image = giftherData["master_variant_images"] as? NSArray {

       print("images are : \(image.count)")

        self._imagesUrl =  String(describing: image)

    } 
This totally wrong.

Comment: @selvaraj: can u please tell me what changes should i do?

Comment: Try AlamofireObjectMapper this is easy to mapping to your objects. https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

Comment: Create image array and add the master_variant_images values to image array and fetch first index and display

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    Alamofire.request(URL.init(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/webdevapp/app/public/spree/products/2/product/ri1.jpg?1476104874")! ).responseData { (response) in

        //debugPrint(response)

        if let image = response.result.value {

            let img = UIImage.init(data: image)

            cell.imageView?.image = img

        }
    }
```

replace this alamofire method hope this helps

Comment: It worked for me. 
Where exactly did you get nil value ?